# Spring Data Couchbase - CrudRepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, couchbase

I am trying to retrieve a document from couchbase using CrudRepository interface. The document is something similar to below and has name CUSTOMER::52663829988929

> {   "DATA": {
>       "FNAME": "Greg",
>       "LNAME": "CLARKE"   },   "KEY": "CUSTOMER::52663829988929" }

The related class is named com.mycompany.xyz.Customer. I created a repository using the below code :

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, String> {

}
```

Code for Customer Class -

```
public class Customer{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Expose @SerializedName("KEY") private String key;
    @Expose @SerializedName("DATA") private Data data;

    public Customer() {
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

Code for Data class -

```
public class Data  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Expose @SerializedName("FNAME") private  String fname;
    @Expose @SerializedName("LNAME") private  String lname;

    // getters and setters

}
```

When I execute the below code , I am getting an empty Customer object -

```
customerRepository.findOne("CUSTOMER::52663829988929")
```

Please can you let me know what I'm missing.

EDIT:

When I looked at the documents in couchbase , it does not have _class attribute. Is this mandatory? Can't Spring Data's CRUDRepo be used to fetch documents that doesn't have _class attribute?

Comment: That single line of code is correct. You need to share more code in order to find the root cause.

Comment: Hi Gergely , I have added additional code that I am using.

Comment: What is that `@Expose` annotation??? Is that from the Gson lib?

Comment: Spring Data is usually used both to persist and retrieve the data, it will expect a certain format for the persisted data, and yes there should be a `_class` attribute...

Comment: Thanks Simon. If the document is not stored using spring data , how can it be retrieved